# using SDK specific API or standard c functions

Tags: c, pjsip

```
gcc (GCC) 4.7.2
PJ SIP 2.1
```

Hello,

I am developing an application that will use the PJSIP API.

Just looking at the API documentation and I see some functions that seem to be just wrappers for the standard C library. i.e. `pj_memset`, `pj_strncpy`, `pj_strlen`, etc.

I can see some alternatives that might be worth considering `pj_strncpy_with_null()` which will always NULL terminate a string. A another advantage could be is that the pjsip uses a `pj_str_t` structure to store the string and the size. Which could be better than using a normal C string.

And is there any point using `pj_size_t` over `size_t` which is portable anyway?

The link for quick reference is here:

```
http://www.pjsip.org/pjlib/docs/html/group__PJ__PSTR.htm
```

It there any real advantage using PJSIP over the standard C library?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: Use the PJSIP API (all of it).

Long answer: It depends.

If you were programming an application for standard Desktops, that is, x86/x64 Windows/Mac/Linux, then no, it wouldn't really matter too much if you used the standard C library or wrappers like the PJSIP functions. Practically, of course, there might be functions that take (as you pointed out) the `pj_str_t` struct instead of a `char *`; it would be easier then to use the PJSIP API just to simplify and remove the need for conversions.

The reason for wrappers, I'm assuming, is to make it easier to develop on embedded devices. I don't mean just ARM or other non-x86 processors—though it could apply there as well; I mean custom embedded devices: things that have a very specific purpose and change infrequently. These embedded devices have very limited capabilities and sometimes even lack an OS. Without an OS, these processors might not have a `malloc` function or the like. Frequently, the libraries associated with the devices, since they are customized so much, are not entirely "standard" and differ in some small way. By having wrappers for everything, PJSIP can avoid most issues and even provide implementations across the board for things such as `strcpy` or `malloc` such that all devices run the "same" code.

Wrappers also provide the means for "hooks." Hooks enable better error messaging (and possibly handling). It's unclear whether PJSIP is doing this (I have never used PJSIP—I am talking from experience using other frameworks), but I am pointing it out just to show why a framework might bother wrapping everything.

In the end, it boils down to your purpose: if you chose to use PJSIP in the first place, then I would go all out and use all of its API. If you are only using it in a few places (for whatever reason) then it probably doesn't matter. Again, it appears that PJSIP is targeting embedded devices (it lists Nokia and even RTOS systems), where it is fairly common to provide wrappers for even "standard" functions. If this is the case, and you are using it in this way, definitely use the entire API.

Comment: Great answer. I'd just like to add that it would also make it easier for the library to change its internals without breaking your code. If they decide `size_t` is not big enough, they can make their `pj_size_t`. That would break your code if you used `size_t` where they expected `pj_size_t`.

Comment: That's a good point. While the names may express similar intent, they do not necessarily indicate the same or similar implementation.

Comment: Errata: I missed one word: _... they can make their `pj_size_t` **larger**_.

Answer (score 1):

Will you be sticking with pjsip?

> PJSIP source code ("The Software") is licensed under both General
>   Public License (GPL) version 2 or later and a proprietary license that
>   can be arranged...

If you think the GPL may be too restrictive for future expansion (such as Android's no-GPL-in-userspace policy) and their proprietary license is not acceptable, you may benefit from using your own portable code/wrappers that you could use with a less restrictive BSD stlye library like [Baresip](http://www.creytiv.com/baresip.html)

There are plenty of other methods to provide needed functionality where the standard C library does not support it, many of which will be better tested (I hate to mention autotools, but... it does support most platforms - some would say too many)  Or you could include implementations/adaptations from [musl-libc](http://www.musl-libc.org/)

Another thing to consider is the C api is based on standards and fairly set in stone while the wrappers in a given project are much more free to break API compatibility from version to version (just ask a glib/gtk programmer)

Comment: Once we have created a demo application from PJSIP. Yes, my company will be purchasing a propriety license from them.